# How can i run class from Prestashop WebService

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.6

So here is my problem.
I have a class created that extends AdminProductsControllerCore.
What it does is if you have one product that you want to split in 3 different products but have the same stock, it will have 1 master and 2 slaves.
For example:
You have `reference` - N101 that has stock 100, but you want to have 3 products with different `reference` N100FR and N100DE.

What the new class does is that if you link the 3 products, all will have the same stock. As soon as you change the stock for one, it will also change it for the other 2.

We also have a connection to a fulfillment system that manages the warehouse stock. This means that the Fulfillment software is connected through WebService to Prestashop and every change in the Fulfillment system to the stock is being sent to Prestashop. This also works very good.
Also to be noted that in the Fulfillment software we have multiple systems linked to import orders, not just prestashop so it means that some orders are never in prestashop, but the stock drops.

Now comes the problem:

If i manually (or by new order) change the stock in Prestashop, all products change qty to the new value.
But if the qty changes in the Fulfillment system, only the master sku changes stock in Prestashop.
So this actually means that the new class that changes the stock when it's manually done in Prestashop (or by creation of new order) does not work.

My question is how can i make it that when the stock is changed, that the class that i created will run?

If there is need for more details, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Stock update does not trigger a full product object update.

I guess your fulfillment system is calling the *stock_available* resource,
so one possible solution is to override the **updateWs()** method
to make sure your code is executed there too.

Comment: You are right. From what I see that's what they are using. And where can I find the updateWS()? Is it in class/webservice/WebserviceRequest.php?

Comment: I now see that there are actually 2 files that contain it.
`classes/Product.php` and `classes/stock/AvailableStock.php`
Can you give an example on what to edit exactly and where to insert it? Because i see this in stock available:

`public function updateWs()
    {
        if ($this->depends_on_stock) {
            return WebserviceRequest::getInstance()->setError(500, Tools::displayError('You cannot update the available stock when it depends on stock.'), 133);
        }
        return $this->update();
    }`

Comment: and this in Products:

`public function updateWs($null_values = false)
    {
        $success = parent::update($null_values);
        if ($success && Configuration::get('PS_SEARCH_INDEXATION')) {
            Search::indexation(false, $this->id);
        }
        Hook::exec('updateProduct', array('id_product' => (int)$this->id));
        return $success;
    }`